# ValueInjecter: Where should I download the binaries? CodePlex or NuGet?

Tags: valueinjecter

I think I have 2 options:

1) Download from CodePlex: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

2) Download from NuGet official package source (currently download count is only 133).

I prefer to download from NuGet, but I'm a little worried about its safety. I have no idea who made the package. Is the package on NuGet made by ValueInjecter's [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112100/omu), or some other trusted user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the codeplex site for now,

the package on nuget is made by the author, but it's not the latest version (sorry)

Comment: Omu have you improved your release flow that Nuget can be used as the primary source?

Comment: @Chris Marisic yes you can use the nuget now